# Get Tasks data using API key

Tags: android, google-tasks-api

I am trying to get google tasks data using API key.

I have referred below link.
http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/source/browse/tasks-v1-json-oauth2-android-sample/src/com/google/api/client/sample/tasks/v1/android/TasksSample.java?repo=samples

In the above link, it is mentioned that get the  API key from Google tasks API access.
But I do not know exactly how to get this API key through code.

Is API key related google accounts?
If it is related to google account, then is it unique for different google accounts?
or
Is API key related to application (which is used to get tasks data)?

how to get google Tasks API key through code?

Answer (score 1):

Generate the API key from [Google API Console](https://code.google.com/apis/console/b/0/). The API key is linked to the Google Account and will be unique to each account.

Comment: I can get account details from account manager. By using account deatils is it possible to get google tasks API key through code?

Comment: @user804343 - No, that's not possible.